# addEventListener for input not working anymore after validation error is thrown

Tags: javascript, jquery

**The problem**

I use a form on a webpage where users fill in all sorts of details. There are 3 fields which generate the input for another field. That field gets generated like this: Firstname + Lastname + Date of birth. However, when a validation error is thrown on the form and the page reloads, the generated input isn't the expected format anymore. Only the Date of birth is then in that input.

It looks like it isn't initializing the Firstname + Lastname field anymore after a validation error is thrown on the page. Any suggestions on how to make it so that the fields gets initialized constantly? Or is there maybe a better way to handle this?

This is the code I use for the generated input

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let studentNoField = document.getElementById('input_7_9');
  let enteredDetails = {
    name: '',
    lastname: '',
    date: ''
  };

  /* set value in the third input: Studentnummer */
  function generateInput() {
    let studentNumber = Object.values(enteredDetails).join('').toLowerCase();
    studentNoField.value = studentNumber;
  }

  /* event listener for first input: Voornaam */
  document.getElementById('input_7_1').addEventListener('input', function(event) {
    enteredDetails.name = event.target.value.replace(/\s/g, '').slice(0, 8);
    generateInput();
  });
  /* event listener for second input: Achternaam */
  document.getElementById('input_7_25').addEventListener('input', function(event) {
    enteredDetails.lastname = event.target.value.replace(/\s/g, '').slice(0, 8);
    generateInput();
  });
  /* event listener for second input: Date */
  document.getElementById('input_7_3').addEventListener('input', function(event) {
    enteredDetails.date = event.target.value.replace(/-/g, '').slice(0, 4);
    generateInput();
  });

  /* Get selected training and format it properly for the PDF */
  jQuery('#input_7_23').change(function(e) {

    var optionChange = jQuery('#input_7_23 option:selected').text().toUpperCase();
    jQuery('#input_7_58').val(optionChange);
  });
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="gform_7" action="/budget/" _lpchecked="1">
   <div>
      <div id="gform_fields_7">
         <div id="field_7_9">
            <label for="input_7_9">Studentnummer
               <input name="input_9" id="input_7_9" type="text" value="" maxlength="20" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
            </div>
         </div>
         <div id="field_7_1">
            <label for="input_7_1">Voornaam</label>
            <div><input name="input_1" id="input_7_1" type="text" value="" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"> </div>
         </div>
         <div id="field_7_25">
            <label for="input_7_25">Achternaam</label>
            <div><input name="input_25" id="input_7_25" type="text" value="" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"> </div>
         </div>
         <div id="field_7_3">
            <label for="input_7_3">Geboortedatum</label>
            <div>
               <input name="input_3" id="input_7_3" type="text" value="" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" aria-describedby="input_7_3_date_format" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true">
               <span id="input_7_3_date_format">DD dash MM dash JJJJ</span>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div>
        <input type="submit" id="gform_submit_button_7" value="Versturen" onclick="if(window[&quot;gf_submitting_7&quot;]){return false;}  window[&quot;gf_submitting_7&quot;]=true;  " onkeypress="if( event.keyCode == 13 ){ if(window[&quot;gf_submitting_7&quot;]){return false;} window[&quot;gf_submitting_7&quot;]=true;  jQuery(&quot;#gform_7&quot;).trigger(&quot;submit&quot;,[true]); }"> 
   </div>
</form>
</body>
</html> 

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Any help or suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: Your snippet doesn't work since there's no html included.

Comment: I just added the HTML @user1599011

Comment: It doesn't work, you have not added any HTML

Comment: Can you see it now @Rishit?

Comment: It's still not part of the snippet, so it doesn't work. You just added a code block at the end, but you need it as part of the runnable snippet! There is a separate box "HTML" in the snippet editor

Comment: Like this? @CherryDT

Comment: No, you put it in the script field and not the html field. But I fixed it for you

Comment: However it still doesn't run because fields input_7_75 and input_7_76 are not existing in your HTML. (Maybe this is your problem?)

Comment: My guess is that you need to put the value back in the inputs when validation fails, or the inputs will be empty and user data will be lost

Comment: @CherryDT Thanks. Sorry I couldn't format it properly myself :') - I've just added the inputs again. Now they should be working.

Comment: Hm what should trigger the validation error? I don't see any client side validation here. If it's on the server, we would need to know how the code looks that renders the page with failed validation.

Answer (score 0):

There were a few non-existing `id`s referenced in your code. In the following snippet I have tried to "correct" these errors, but I also went further: I removed all repetitions, thereby following the DRY principle "Don't repeat yourself". The "input"-event listener now works for all elements of the `inps` array. There  is, however one differentiation: the first two elements are limited to 8 characters while the date is limited to 4: `.slice(0,i<2?8:4)`.

```js
const [stNr, ...inps]=[9, 1, 25, 3].map(n=> document.getElementById(`input_7_${n}`));
inps.forEach(inp=>inp.addEventListener("input",()=>
  stNr.value=inps.map((el,i)=>
    el.value.replace(/[\s-]/g,"").slice(0,i<2?8:4).toLowerCase()
  ).join(""))
)
```

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="gform_7" action="/budget/" _lpchecked="1">
  <div>
    <div id="gform_fields_7">
      <div id="field_7_9">
        <label for="input_7_9">Studentnummer</label>
        <input name="input_9" id="input_7_9" type="text" value="" maxlength="20" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="field_7_1">
      <label for="input_7_1">Voornaam</label>
      <div><input name="input_1" id="input_7_1" type="text" value="" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"> </div>
    </div>
    <div id="field_7_25">
      <label for="input_7_25">Achternaam</label>
      <div><input name="input_25" id="input_7_25" type="text" value="" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"> </div>
    </div>
    <div id="field_7_3">
      <label for="input_7_3">Geboortedatum</label>
      <div>
        <input name="input_3" id="input_7_3" type="text" value="" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" aria-describedby="input_7_3_date_format" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true">
        <span id="input_7_3_date_format">DD dash MM dash JJJJ</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" id="gform_submit_button_7" value="Versturen">
  </div>
</form>
```

I removed your jQuery statements at the end of your script, as they referred to non-existent ids. These statements can definitely also be re-written in Vanilla JS, if necessary.

And, as @CherryDT already mentioned: there is no validation code visible here. If it happens on the server then it is the server's responsibility to produce a suitable response that allows the client to render the page with the previously (possibly annotated) content.